# How to stop addObject from overwriting all previous objects in a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode

addObject is overwriting all the previous cells. So if the array is size 4, adding the objects increases the size, but it also overwrites all other cells with the same thing.

```
groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[groups addObject:[[Group alloc] init]];
[[groups objectAtIndex:0] setGroupName:@"cs480"];
[[groups objectAtIndex:0] setPassword:@"apple1"];

[groups addObject:[[Group alloc] init]];
[[groups objectAtIndex:1] setGroupName:@"cs481"];
[[groups objectAtIndex:1] setPassword:@"apple2"];

+(void) print{
    NSLog(@"size: %lu",(unsigned long)[groups count]);

    for(int i = 0; i < [groups count]; i++){
        Group *group = [groups objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@\t%@\n",[group getGroupName], [group getPassword]);

    }

}
```

The group class is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "Group.h"
#import "Person.h"
#import "Pie.h"

@implementation Group
NSString* groupName;
NSString* password;
NSMutableArray *groupMembers;
NSMutableArray *skillsOfMembers;
-(id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
         NSLog(@"inside group constructor");
         groupMembers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         skillsOfMembers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         groupName = [[NSString alloc]init];
         password =  [[NSString alloc]init];
     }
     return self;
 }

 -(NSInteger) authenticate:(NSString *)checkGroupName :(NSString *)checkPassword{
    if([checkGroupName isEqualToString:groupName]&&[checkPassword isEqualToString:password]){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

-(void) setGroup:(NSMutableArray*)newGroupMembers{
    groupMembers = newGroupMembers;
}
-(NSMutableArray*) getGroup{
    return groupMembers;
}
-(Person*) getPerson:(int) index{
    return [groupMembers objectAtIndex:index];
}
-(void) setPerson:(int) index :(Person*) newPerson{
    Person* person = [groupMembers objectAtIndex:index];
    person = newPerson;
}


-(NSMutableArray*) getSkillsOfPerson:(int)index{
    return [skillsOfMembers objectAtIndex:index];
}
-(void) setSkillsOfPerson:(Pie*) newSkills :(int)index{
    Pie *skillsOfMember = [skillsOfMembers objectAtIndex:index];
    skillsOfMember = newSkills;
}    


-(void) setGroupName:(NSString*) newName{
    groupName = [newName copy];
 }

-(NSString*) getGroupName{
    return groupName;
}

-(void) setPassword:(NSString*) newPassword{
     password = [newPassword copy];
}

-(NSString*) getPassword{
     return password;
}
@end
```

The output is

```
2014-11-10 13:23:19.013 Balanced Team Pie[1964:66289] size: 2
2014-11-10 13:23:19.013 Balanced Team Pie[1964:66289] cs481 apple2
2014-11-10 13:23:19.014 Balanced Team Pie[1964:66289] cs481 apple2
```

What is the issue?

Comment: The bug is in your Group class. Please post the code for that.

Comment: At least one of the bugs is that you are operating on the object at index 0 both times. `-addObject:` adds to the **end** of the array. The second `Group` that you add never has `-setGroupName:` or `-setPassword:` called on it (given the code that's shown).

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. I added the group class. I changed the indecies to 1, but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

These:

```
@implementation Group
NSString* groupName;
NSString* password;
NSMutableArray *groupMembers;
NSMutableArray *skillsOfMembers;
```

are not instance variables. They are just global variables. They are declared at file scope. The fact that they come between `@implementation` and its corresponding `@end` means nothing to the compiler.

Effectively, there's one set of variables for the whole program, rather than one set of variables for each instance of the `Group` class.

You probably meant:

```
@implementation Group
{
    NSString* groupName;
    NSString* password;
    NSMutableArray *groupMembers;
    NSMutableArray *skillsOfMembers;
}
```

The curly braces are required to make the variables instance variables.

Comment: Hey I actually figured it out, but it was exactly this. I'm kind of learning as I'm going haha. I really appreciate the help.